# Type binding asp core 2.2

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, model-binding, typeconverter

My asp core api gets as input object with the following json structure:

```
{
     "id": 1,
     "zoneDate": {
         "zone": "Paris/France",
         "dateTime": "2019-04-02T00:00:00"
      }
}
```

I wanna convert this object to the following model:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I have a service that knows how to convert complex json object `zoneDate` to build in .Net `DateTime` with an offset.

I need api to do the conversion automatically (in model binding) whenever it sees `DateTime` in the model, which is marked with some custom attribute (or built in if any). Any ideas to do that elegantly? Is there something like `TypeConverter` that can work on single `simple type` property and that can take `parameter injected through constructor`? Any help is deeply appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I need the binding on the property level, not on the model level. I mean if I use model binder, then I need to create it for EACH and EVERY new model which have `DateTime` props that should be created from `ZoneDate` json. That's not what I want. I want to treat `ZoneDate` as simple type, when I convert it to `DateTime` which has an attribute or some name convention

**UPDATE:**
Finally, the @jpgrassi advice was implemented.

> Instead of writing these binders, that just hide the complexity away..
>   why not introduce a type ZoneDate that contains those fields and let
>   the default modelbinder do its work? In the end, what will you gain
>   from accepting that format, and binding it yourself? I think having a
>   type is way better. You let the compiler help you with stuff
>   (refactoring and etc). Plus your code is simple.

Comment: You can use a custom model binder. if you have your service to convert it, you can even get it via the DI container. Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-model-binder-sample

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I misunderstood your question. It's a bit more complicated then I thought. I have some questions: Do you expect to always get this `zoneDate` format in your API? Right now I don't know a way to automatically (even with attributes) to get the incoming json string and assign to that property. With a custom binder, you can register it automatically, but if this will appear in other models, then I would go a different way to solve this.

Comment: Instead of writing these binders, that just hide the complexity away.. why not introduce a type `ZoneDate` that contains those fields and let the default modelbinder do its work? In the end, what will you gain from accepting that format, and binding it yourself? I think having a type is way better. You let the compiler help you with stuff (refactoring and etc). Plus your code is simple.

Comment: @jpgrassi Sir, your point is really reasonable. I just wanted to get some way to perform the conversion automatically, behind the scene. Because, anyway at some point I should convert `ZoneDate` to `DateTime`. I don't even want my API to know about Z`oneDate`, because from business standpoint it shouldn't be aware about it

Comment: @jpgrassi also, model binders don't work with `FromBody` ValueProvider. Additional actions need to be done to fix that. :-(

Comment: Well, Business stand point also don't care with binders and custom code that can break easily :).  It's clear that introducing a model has more advantages than disadvantages . You are stating the issues yourself.

Comment: @jpgrassi Finally I did what you've suggested about 1-to-1 mapping. After some thinking time, I've realized that "magic behind the scene" is a way worse than simple, readable and predictable code, despite the fact the it doesn't make "magic behind the scene". Thank you!

Comment: I guess that's a reasonable compromise. As a tip: If you don't want to "leak" this to your "real business" classes, like Domain Entities, you can try to do some conversion between them, so they at least are constrained into your "web" only project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Paris/France` is not valid Timezone text format, the correct should be `Europe/Paris`.

Then I assume you want to convert the given the time

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using TimeZoneConverter;

namespace ParseJsonDateTimeZone
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"id\": 1,\"zoneDate\":{\"zone\":\"Europe/Paris\",\"dateTime\":\"2019-04-02T00:00:00\"}}";
            Console.WriteLine(new Model(json));
        }

        public class Model
        {
            public Model(string json)
            {
                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
                Id = (int) jObject["id"];
                JToken zoneDate = jObject["zoneDate"];
                TimeZoneInfo tzi;
                try
                {
                    tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(zoneDate["zone"].ToString());
                }
                catch(TimeZoneNotFoundException)
                {
                    // Fallback to UTC or do something else?
                    tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("UTC");
                }
                CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                DateTime dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Parse(zoneDate["dateTime"].ToString()), tzi);
                DateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, tzi );
            }
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've stated in my question: 
*I have a service that knows how to convert complex json object zoneDate to build in .Net DateTime with an offset.*. Therefore the question isn't about conversion, but about global mechanism which can map all `zoneDate` to `DateTime` for all asp core responses. `ModelBinder` is example for such mapping, but it works for requests, while I need such mapping for responses. Anyway, thank you sir, for your effort